# HttpClient post request for WebApi using asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, curl, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to consume WebApi but I'm having issues. My 'IsSuccessStatusCode' is always false and I have 404 in response.

I have tried multiple methods but can't be able to do it correctly.

Constants:

```
const string baseUri = ""; // base url of API
const string setDealFlagUri = "Deals/SetDealFlag";
```

Method 1, using PostAsync:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri);

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("deadId", "3"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("flagValueToSet", "true")
    });

    var response = await client.PostAsync(setDealFlagUri, content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Method 2, using PostAsJsonAsync:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri);
    DealFlag content = new DealFlag
    {
        deadId = 3,
        flagValueToSet = true
    };

    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(setDealFlagUri, content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

WebApi request detail:

Curl:

> curl -X POST --header 'Accept: application/json' '{baseApiurl}/Deals/SetDealFlag?dealId=3&flagValueToSet=true'

Request URL

> {baseApiurl}/Deals/SetDealFlag?dealId=3&flagValueToSet=true

Response Body

```
{
  "Successful": true,
  "ErrorMessages": [],
  "ValidationResults": {
    "IsValid": false,
    "ValidationErrors": []
  }
}
```

Response Headers

```
{
  "pragma": "no-cache",
  "date": "Wed, 24 Aug 2016 18:38:01 GMT",
  "content-encoding": "gzip",
  "server": "Microsoft-IIS/8.0",
  "x-aspnet-version": "4.0.30319",
  "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET",
  "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "cache-control": "no-cache",
  "content-length": "198",
  "expires": "-1"
}
```

Please help me to use this webapi function correctly.
Thanks!

Comment: What the problem? `IsSuccessStatusCode` is always `false`? If so what is in the `response`?

Comment: yes, 'IsSuccessStatusCode' is always false. and I have 404 in response.

Comment: @Saadi 404 - means NOT FOUND. So check your url first

Comment: URL seems ok for me. I have also added my url constants to my question. You can check it. It seems ok

Comment: @Saadi I'm not totally sure but as I can see you send your data via URL not as a form (using cURL). Did you try POST your request to the `https://energydevdealswebservices20160719041846.azurewebsites.net/Deals/SetDealFlag?deadid=3&flagValueToSet=true` url instead of sending data as a content to the `https://energydevdealswebservices20160719041846.azurewebsites.net/Deals/SetDealFlag`?

Comment: can you tell me how I can send it using HttpClient?

Comment: @Saadi something like that  `client.PostAsync("https://energydevdealswebservices20160719041846.azurewebsites.net/Deals/SetDealFlag?dealId=3&flagValueToSet=true", content);`

Comment: It's not working using this way too.

Comment: @Saadi I wrote simple console app that checks your issue. Check it out too. Code is here https://gist.github.com/feeeper/d94c6576bfba766590b5c4e97b86af65

Comment: @Saadi As I said previously if I send params via URL I got success status code. Otherwise I got 404 error. I wrote about it in the gist.

Comment: @Saadi Do you resolve the issue? If no add your web api method here pease

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that your controller method has signature like

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage SetDealFlag(int dealId, bool flagValueToSet)
```

Am I right? If your answer is "Yes" so your method wants parameters in the URL.

And so you get 404 error becouse no one of yours Web API methods matches to that URL.

Send your parameters `dealId` and `flagValueToSet` in the URL is the solution.

I wrote simple console app for testing my theory and it works perfectly:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    try
    {
      // Next two lines are not required. You can comment or delete that lines without any regrets
      const string baseUri = "{base-url}";
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri);

      var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
      {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("deadId", "3"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("flagValueToSet", "true")
      });

      // response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode == true and no errors
      var response = client.PostAsync($"{baseUri}/Deals/SetDealFlag?dealId=3&flagValueToSet=true", null); 

      // response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode == false and 404 error
      // var response = client.PostAsync($"{baseUri}/Deals/SetDealFlag", content); 
      response.Wait();
      if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
        return;
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      throw;
    }
  }
}
```