# MVC Method receiving null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, console-application

I'm trying to pass 2 parameters from Console app to a method in ASP.NET Controller.
When I try to do it, the parameters keep receiving null values.

Here is the code on the Clientside

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44331/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
              
                { "user12",u},
                { "pass12",p},

            };
            List<Dictionary<string, string>> x = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            x.Add(data);
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("Home/Receiver", x).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("success!!");            
            }
```

Where `u` and `p` are parameters that the user defines when the console app runs.

Here is the code for the method I want to pass the parameters into

```
[HttpPost]  
public void Receiver(string user12, string pass12) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("user is " + user12 +"and pass is"  + pass12);
}
```

Basically, I want to pass the parameters `u` and `p` from the client side to the parameters `user12` and `pass12` in the method. However, when I run the code, the value is user12 and pass12 is null!!

When I try to do a post request via postman, it works.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpClient post request for WebApi using asp.net mvc application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139501/httpclient-post-request-for-webapi-using-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public static async Task GetData(string u, string p)
{
           using (var client = new HttpClient())
          {
            var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
            var baseAddress = "https://localhost:44331";
            var api = "/Home/Receiver";
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
           var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
              
                { "user12",u},
                { "pass12",p},

            };
     var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        var contentData = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(baseAddress + api,contentData);
                        
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(stringData);
            }
       }
}
```

this is your program

```
public class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
   {
        var u="user";
         var p="password";
        await GetData(u,p);
        Console.WriteLine("finished");
        
    }

    public static async Task GetData(string u, string p)
    {
          ...code above
    }

 
}
```

and fix your action

add Model class

```
public class Model
    {
        public string User12 { get; set; }
        public string Pass12 { get; set; }
    }
```

and correct the action header

```
        public void Receiver(Model model) 
        {
             MessageBox.Show("user is " + model.User12 +"and pass is"  + model.Pass12);
        }
```

Comment: Hi serge, i managed to solve the problem using the link TAHA SULTAN TEMURI sent, however, i thank you for responding to the question so quickly, have a good day